# App with Webview. How to create a link on my site to create shortcut on desktop for opening that page in Webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, shortcut

I have an app with a WebView in which my simple PHP site is displaying. How to make a "create shortcut" link on my website, so when I click this link, it will create a desktop shortcut for that page to open in-app webview with that page opened? Or it easier to do it via Button under WebView?